# Inheritance and Casting

Tags: c#, inheritance

If I want to execute that function it doesn't work.

```
showdict(RedWineMenu._RedWineMenu);
```

My classes:

```
public class RedWine : Wine
{
    public override string Prepare
    {
        get
        {
            return $"Well, {this.Name} wine temperture's same as room temperture. \n All you need to do is pour it into a glass and serve.";
        }
    }
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{base.Name} ({this.Year})";
        }
    }
}

public class Wine : Drink
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class Drink : Idrink
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    
    public virtual string Prepare { get; }

}
```

This function in the same class as `showdict`:

```
private void showdict (Dictionary<int, Drink> dict) 
{
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} - {item.Value.Name}");
    }
}


public class RedWineMenu : Menu
{

    public Dictionary<int, RedWine> _RedWineMenu { get; private set; }



public class Menu
{
    public string KindOfDrink { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Here you can see the worning]

I do'nt get it. If "Drink" is the futher class of RedWine - why can't insert it into that dictionary?
How can I do it?

Comment: You have one dictionary that is `Dictionary<int, Drink>` and one that is `Dictionary<int, RedWine>`. These are not the same thing. (Inheritance doesn't affect generics the same way. Look up "covariance" and "contravariance".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` type is not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) meaning you cannot do what you are trying here. However, there is a workaround if you make your `showdict` generic and using a [type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), like this:

```
private void showdict<T>(Dictionary<int, T> dict) 
    where T : Drink
{
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} - {item.Value.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: What happend in the back of it?
Why do I need to add <T> to the name of the function? It does'nt return anything.. 
It just print it

Comment: I suggest reading about generics in C#, here's a good start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/